# MVVM UpdateSourceTrigger

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, updatesourcetrigger

I'm working on an MVVM app and have a view that is used to modify a number of network parameters (IP, SubnetMask, etc).

The view contains a number of text boxes bound to properties in a `NetworkConfigViewModel`:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="IP" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>

... etc
```

The view also contains a button called `Save Configuration`.  The button is bound to a RelayCommand in the ViewModel that takes care of saving the configuration to the remote device on request.

I would like to modify the textbox bindings to use `UpdateSourceTrigger="Explicit"` so that the ViewModel only gets updated when the user explicitly clicks 'Save Configuration', rather than updating as values are modified.

I understand that I'll need to call `BindingExpression.UpdateSource()` for each text box.  How can I do this in an MVVM-friendly way?  Adding a new RelayCommand to the ViewModel that is aware of the UI elements doesn't seem correct.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly, letting ViewModel know about View too much isn't good. I'd better update a copy of settings, and let binding do all works for me. Once user clicks 'Save Configuration' button I would propagate changes further to repository, model or whatever...

Answer (score 1):

Don't implement this functionality in the bindings to your view model.  Implement it in your view model.  The properties of the view model should always reflect what's in the view - it's called a view model because it's a model of the view, after all.

I'm guessing that you're asking this question because you've implemented the view model with properties like this:

```
public string MyProperty
{
   get { return _Model.MyProperty; } 
   set
   {
      _Model.MyProperty=value;
      OnPropertyChanged("MyProperty");
   }
}
```

Don't do this.  Store the property values in private backing fields, and update the model properties in the "Save Configuration" method.

Comment: "it's called a view model because it's a model of the view" - I thought it was a View of the Model

Answer (score 1):

So referring back to your example:

If the ViewModel has private backing fields for its properties instead of exposing the properties of the Model like so-

```
private string _myProperty;

public string MyProperty
{

    get { return _myProperty; }
    set
    {
        if (_myProperty != value)
        {
            _myProperty = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MyProperty");
        }
    }
}
```

What will the controls in the View bind to?  If you bind to a property that only exposes a private backing field, how would any data ever get into the view?  For instance, a TextBox couldn't bind to the ViewModel property, MyProperty, anymore because it isn't exposing Model.MyProperty.  It's simply exposing _myProperty.  If you do bind to Model.MyProperty like so in the View:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Model.MyProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" />
<Button Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" />
```

...you will get data into the TextBox.  Now, how do we update the model with the updated value from the TextBox when the Save button is pressed?

```
private void SaveExecute()
{
    // How do we update the Model.MyProperty value?
}
```